# How to cut strings inside a list in python

Tags: python

For example the list will contain

```py
list1 = ["mathematics", "sciences", "historical"]
```

and i only need the middle parts of the string

```py
output_list = ["thema", "ience", "stori"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python list comprehension. [Please read it up, it's useful.](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)

Also, python slicing and indexing. [You can read more here](https://railsware.com/blog/python-for-machine-learning-indexing-and-slicing-for-lists-tuples-strings-and-other-sequential-types/).

For the problem you post:

```py
output_list = [word[2:7] for word in list1]

print(output_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string slicing for this:

```py
x = "abcde"
print(x[1:4])  # prints elements [1, 4), i.e., "bcd"
```